# How to know which user has generated a Firebase event?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase real-time database in my project and for now, I am *not* using any authentication method meaning that all sign-in methods on Firebase are disabled and there is no rule defined on the Firebase database too:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement a collaborative text editing app so several users at the same time might be updating the same text. So in my app I am observing the corresponding text editing events sent by Firebase and therefore can keep the text synced for all users working on the same content.

My question is, when a Text Editing event is received by the app how come I can know who (which user) has made that change on Firebase (Whether the event I just received is as a result of a change in the text by User1 or User2 or so on). Because currently, I know that somebody has made a change in the text (because I receive an event) but I don't know who had made it. Any help? Thanks

Any general guidance would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify users without requiring them to sign in, you're looking for [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth). In Objective-C this is as simple as:

```
[[FIRAuth auth]
 signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error) {
   // ...
 }];
```

And then you can identify the user with:

```
[[[FIRAuth auth].currentUser].uid];
```

Comment: Hey Frank... Is that what the OP was asking? I think they are looking for more of a way to know which user wrote a certain piece data to Firebase when everyone is anonymous. In other words - maybe they are looking for a way to (automatically) tie the data that was written to a specific user (name for example). In that case when data is written, it would need to be 'tagged' with something that identifies the user. So the child nodes would contain /updatedText: "new text" along with /userName: "Frank" for example. Or... I could just not be understanding the question. ;-)

Comment: You could be right. I wasn't clear to me. It'd definitely be good if you write an answer for that approach.